# How to fix expander button in displaying row details in WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf

I am using row details , in WPF datagrid. When i press Expander button to expand/collapse the  row details line, expander button goes down and its needed to change mouse cursor to further press the button. how to fix expander button in this case?

Comment: Post what you tried? More code

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.